# Which Apache Tomcat version should I use?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Each Apache Tomcat version implements different version of Java EE specification and Java EE is backwards compatible. My question is: I have a Java EE 5 application. Should I deploy it on Apache Tomcat 6 (Java EE 5 implementation) or Apache Tomcat 7 (Java EE 6 implementation)? What are the pros and cons?

Pros:
In Apache Tomcat 7 are some improvements: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Cons:
???

Comment: For those who this this question is opinion-based: This IS NOT opinion-based question! I'm not looking for opinions! I'm looking for best practice and expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost take the latest major version. Tomcat team is constantly improving the product. You can enjoy better performance and robustness.

I'd just recommend you to afraid to upgrade to the first minor releases of the newest major version. But Tomcat 7 is good very good.